# Autoelectrics: Testing components off 12v battery

Tags: relay, automotive, solenoid, circuit-protection

I'm quite good with mechanics and am just starting to learn more about electrics specifically applicable to automotive. One thing I am still yet to get the grasp of is the way electricity behaves. It seems some things I read say 'a device will only use (draw from the circuit) as much power as it needs', but other learnings contradict this. So this question is about overloading components / component protection.

When playing with little electronic kits and building a simple LED light circuit one of the steps is to add a resistor so that the LED doesn't blow out.

This got me thinking; this weekend I was having trouble starting one of my classic motorcycles using it's electric starter and I was able to isolate the problem to the starter solenoid. My process of elimination was to jump across the solenoid to check that the starter motor engaged which it did. I then disconnected the solenoid and measured the voltage for the two wires going into it (which complete the circuit of the starter switch). I got ~12v when pressing the switch so that part works fine. The problem must be the starter solenoid.

The next test I did (which wasn't really necessary but I was interested to see the result) was to check for continuity across the main terminals (which go from the battery to the starter motor) by applying the two wires (which would otherwise come from the starter switch circuit) directly to the battery. The solenoid clicked as it was doing before but no continuity was found, which if it worked I should have.

My question is, if this relay was good. Would applying it directly to the battery damage the relay? My basic understanding is that the starter switch wires are on the main 10A fused electrics circuit, and the battery > starter motor is a 30A fused circuit.

Depending on the answers above, what about doing this with other components? Could you use jumpers to hook the headlight up to the battery without damaging?

If the answers are yes, why isn't a resistor required like in the basic electronics kit?

Thanks, and sorry if this is a very basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When everything is working correctly, the fuse doesn't do anything. The fuse is there in case something goes wrong and a component that should "only use as much power as it needs" starts to use way too much. If this happens then the fine wire in the fuse gets hot, melts, and saves the rest of your wiring from burning out.

The components in your motorcycle are designed to work with a 12V circuit, so it's safe to connect the battery directly to the starter solenoid coil (as long as it isn't faulty).

It's not safe to connect the battery directly across the starter solenoid contacts. These contacts are a switch to supply power to the starter motor. The starter motor will draw as much power as it needs when the starter solenoid contacts are closed

If you needed to use an LED in your motorcycle, you would add a resistor to the LED and package this as a single part, so that the part (LED + resistor) would only draw as much power as it needed.

Some parts do draw more power than they need. Often there is a "ballast" resistor in series with the ignition coil primary. This does the same job as the resistor in your LED circuit. It limits the current in the coil when the motor is running. During starting, when the battery voltage is drooping because it's powering the starter motor, the ballast resistor is bypassed to increase the current in the ignition coil